# Is API Polling more efficient than WebSockets for infrequent updates?

Tags: python-3.x, api, websocket

I am working on building a trading algorithm for cryptocurrencies and have added several different exchanges.

for the last 4 exchanges I added, I use the exchange api endpoint to retrieve ticker prices for all coins (I make one api call every 5 minutes per exchange).

I started working on implementing Coinbase Pro which does not have an endpoint to import all ticker prices at once.

Based on my current coding experience I came up with two options...

Option A: make 30 API Calls once every 5 minutes to import price data.

or

Option B: Connect through web-sockets on 30 different channels and update a dictionary with the most recent updates and send to SQL at intervals of 5 minutes.



**My concerns:**

Coinbase is very active and there seems to be multiple updates per second when only connected to 2 web-sockets.

### **Is it wasteful to use websockets in this scenario?**

I am not building a high frequency trading strategy so minor latency is not a concern. At the same time I am concerned that due to http hangups/timeouts there could be a scenario where 30 requests could take over a minute.

**AS well if API polling is the best solution, will I be able to reduce latency using grequests (for async http requests), urllib3 (connection pooling), or httplib (by keeping connections open)?**

I apologize if this is a dumb question I have only a year of coding experience and I cannot seem to find the right solution for this situation on google/stackoverflow.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

best regards,

Slurpgoose